# bidirectional tcp socket problems in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client, bidirectional

I'm trying to implement a TCP client in C which needs to work as follows:

- Ability to open a connection to a given server
- Ability to send arbitrary data to the server through the established connection, and
- Ability to receive arbitrary data from the server (think of it as responses to the 'questions' that my client sent to the server).

For example, the client should be able to open a connection to an arbitrary HTTP server, send the 'HEAD' message and print the response that arrives from the HTTP server.

(My goal is to create a generic 'TCP client plugin' for a specific software environment that I'm using for my daily work and which lacks networking abilities. I know the SDK of my environment quite well, but I don't really have a deep experience in socket programming.)

Currently, I have 2 separate threads for sending and receiving data. The workflow of the receiver thread (which starts automatically as soon as the server address & port is set by the user) is the following one (here I only mention the main sequence of socket calls):

```
globalSocket = socket(); // Create socket and store it globally
bind(); // Bind the local port
connect(); // Connect to remote host & port
listen(); // Listen to the socket
while (isAlive) {
  select(... &readfds ...); // Check for ready reader descriptors
  accept(); // Accept the incoming connection
  recv(); // Receive data from server
}
close(); // End the connection
```

The sender thread is quite simple, it uses the `globalSocket` created by the receiver thread to execute the `send()` command.

Now, here's my problem: I can open connections to remote servers without any problem. I can also send any arbitrary data without any problem (I confirmed that the data that I send actually arrives to the server side without problems). However, I can't get any data back from the server. After some tests, it seems that `select` would never return with a positive value.

I tried a lot of modifications in my code (like changing parameters to `select`, omitting `listen` etc.), I read Beej's guide at least 10 times during this very day and tried every ad-hoc change that I just could imagine, but the behaviour is still the same. Therefore, before I start asking specific questions with specific code excerpts, I'd like to know whether my approach to this problem was correct or whether I'm having some serious conceptual problems here.

Thanks indeed for your answers,

Ádám

P.S. I couldn't post this codepart in the comments as it is too long; here's the code snippet that manages the `select` - `accept` - `recv` cycle:

```
while ( thread->isActive ) {
   // Accept connection
   timeVal.tv_sec = TIMEOUT_SEC;
   timeVal.tv_usec = TIMEOUT_USEC;
   FD_ZERO( & fileDescriptor );
   FD_SET( socketDescriptor, & fileDescriptor ); // socketDescriptor is the global socket
   result = select ( FD_SETSIZE, & fileDescriptor, NULL, NULL, & timeVal );
   if ( result > 0 ) {
      post ( "select" ); // This line is actually never reached
      connectionDescriptor = accept ( socketDescriptor, ( struct sockaddr * ) & clientAddress, & clientLength ); // connectionDescriptor is the local socket created by accept
      if ( connectionDescriptor < 0 ) { // Some error happened
         outlet_int ( thread->parent->statusOutlet, errno );
      } else {
         // Receive data
         data.clear ( ); // 'data' is an std::vector of chars that stores the incoming data and makes it accessible for the rest of the environment
         size = thread->parent->bufferSize;
         buffer = new unsigned char [ size ]; // this buffer is used for receiving the data from 'recv'
         receivedBytes = 1;
         while ( receivedBytes > 0 ) {
            receivedBytes = recv ( connectionDescriptor, ( char * ) buffer, size, 0 );
            if ( receivedBytes < 0 ) { // Socket error
               outlet_int ( thread->parent->statusOutlet, errno );
            }
            data.insert ( data.end ( ), buffer, buffer + receivedBytes );
         }
         delete [ ] buffer;
#ifdef WIN_VERSION
         closesocket ( connectionDescriptor );
#else
         close ( connectionDescriptor );
#endif
         // Output received data
         ... blah ... blah ... blah
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: The general idea seems correct. One thing you definitely should not do is call `listen` and `connect` on the same socket. It's one or the other. Listen for incoming connections or make an outgoing connection. `bind` isn't necessary for outgoing connections either, unless you want to use a different IP address than the one the kernel picks by default.

Comment: @AlanCurry Thanks, well, I was also very unsure about the necessity of `listen`. With `bind`, I was a bit confused, as Beej's guide states that it's not needed while many people told here and there that it's better to have it. Anyway, I already tried removing those codeparts and still no success...

Comment: you're going to have to show more code. especially the `select` and the `fd_set` initializations.

Comment: @AlanCurry Thank you. Here's the excerpt for the `select` cycle:

Comment: @AlanCurry OK, this was too long to post it here. I added it to my main inquiry.

Comment: After the select you should print the error, if there was one, as in `if(result<0) { perror("select"); }` or write it to a debug logfile, or syslog, or something.

Comment: Since you only have one descriptor in your thread, can you debug first by doing a blocking `recv` in your read thread?

Comment: I checked in the meantime. the result of the select is **always** 0 for some reason.

Comment: OK, I made some more tests. It turns out that if I only disable `receive`, but keep `accept`, I'd always get Error 22 (EINPROGRESS - The connect request failed because a previous connect was already in progress), which I don't really understand. If I also drop the `accept`-related part and keep only `recv`, then I don't get anything (my test is that I open a connection to google.com on port 80 and try to fetch the header of the index page). So maybe that's the problem.

Comment: `accept` goes with `listen` - you shouldn't use it on a socket that does a `connect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are several independent issues here, which are split between several answers and comments, so I'm going to summarize them.

The sender thread is OK. However, the connector/listener thread should look as follows:

```
socket();
connect();
while (isAlive) {
   if (select(... &readfds ...) > 0) {
      recv();
   }
}
close();
```

Regarding the originally posted code excerpt, the `while` cycle that was being used to handle `recv` is a conceptual error and should be removed, since it would block the thread - which would make the `select` statement unnecessary (since in that case, `select` would have no practical effect).

It should also be pointed out that if `recv` returns 0, that means that the socket was closed by the remote peer, so in that case the `while (isAlive)` loop should be aborted even if `isAlive` was not set to false by the parent thread. However, an extra `close`  statement is not needed inside the loop (which was also a conceptual error in the original code).

Answer (score 2):

Others already commented on incompatibility of [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) and [`listen(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/listen.2.html). You don't really need [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) there either.

The most common mistake with using [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) is **not re-initializing file descriptor sets** on each iteration. `select(2)`'s second to forth arguments are **input-output**, so you have to redo them every time.

#### Edit 0:

After you posted your code, let me add that you are not at all benefiting from I/O demultiplexing that `select(2)` gives you. There's also well-known race between being woken up from `select(2)` by new connecting attempt and client dropping that connection before you enter blocking `accept(2)`.

If you are not keen on going the non-blocking route (the preferred way of using `select(2)`, `poll(2)`, `epoll(7)`, `kqueue(2)`, etc.), you might as well get rid of the `select(2)` and just accept and handle client connections in a loop.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Actually I was also a bit confused about these. Regarding the re-initialization, I'm doing it each time before calling `select`. I'm actually re-initializing even the timeout values, as I read somewhere that `select` might also alter those on some platforms...

Comment: This annoyance is one reason why `poll()` is less of a headache. That, and better granularity for fd polling. That being said, `select()` *is* very useful for microsleeps.

Comment: Regarding **Edit 0**: what I don't actually know is, without using `select`, how could I interrupt the listener thread from the main thread of my application? As far as I understood, `recv` would block the thread and there would be no way (except a forced thread kill) to stop it when the functionality is no longer needed (for example, if the user wants to disconnect from the actual host and connect to another one). Is there something that I overlooked?

Comment: OK, I guess I understand why you said that, since I had another `while` loop inside the original one which was blocking the thread anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, are you physically receiving the packets from the remote server? I ask because I ran into a similar problem during an assignment and when I ran tcpdump, it did not show any received packets either. The issue turned out to be a firewall which obviously allows outgoing traffic but blocks all incoming packets...

Comment: Hmmm, good point. I didn't actually check that. What I'm doing as a real-life test is, that I'm opening a connection to www.google.com on port 80 and send a 'HEAD' message. When I do that with telnet, I do get an answer. However, my code doesn't get one... But I'll check with Wireshark or some similar tool and see...

Comment: Ummm, if you are opening the connection on your client and the server REPLIES to that, firewalls shouldn't be an issue. I was assuming that you had control of the server as well, which was true in my case. Unsolicited incoming connection requests do get dropped by firewalls :-)
Anyways wireshark testing will do no harm. You can test whether the outgoing request is well formed by doing a byte by byte comparison with the corresponding telnet outgoing packet.
All the best!